# Use radio button name twice

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button, label

I have a multi step form with 3 different "pages". 1 and 2 are for regular user input and page 3 is a summary from 1 and 2. Page 1 has some radio buttons. I'd like to show these in page 3 again (they should be editable). I don't want to use to different names, because they show exact the same... how can I achieve this? Here is the code for better understanding.

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-1">
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="a" value="1" checked>
  <label for="1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="a" value="2">
  <label for="2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="page-2">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
<div class="page-3">
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="a" value="1">
  <label for="1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="a" value="2">
  <label for="2">2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: it's okay to use the same value for the name attribute, but not the id ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use twice the same `id`. *Also to avoid styling issues , you should not use a number as a first letter for an attribute value (from old specification ) see : [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)*.

here is an example allowing a single `input` to be used by more than 1 `label` . Labels will need to be inside a sibbling of the input in order to style them.

possible working example with div sibblings of inputs:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}

input#a1:checked ~ div label[for="a1"],
input#a2:checked ~ div label[for="a2"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="radio" id="a1" name="a" value="1" checked>
  <input type="radio" id="a2" name="a" value="2">
<div class="page-1">
  <label for="a1">1</label>
  <label for="a2">2</label>
</div>

<div class="page-2">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>

<div class="page-3">
  <label for="a1">1</label>
  <label for="a2">2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: One question: Do you know why [this](https://jsfiddle.net/u5vdtg8k/) doesn't work?

Comment: @xif80599 as stated in my answer :  ***Also to avoid styling issues , you should not use a number as a first letter for an attribute value (old specification ).***  add a letter in front of id like i did in the snippet ;)  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 0):

use different `id=''` everytime.

```
  <div class="page-3">
      <input type="radio" id="3" name="a" value="1">
      <label for="1">1</label>
      <input type="radio" id="4" name="a" value="2">
      <label for="2">2</label>
    </div>
```